# How to dynamically set list of headers in ktor?

Tags: android, android-room, ktor

```
@Dao
interface TokenDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertToken(token: TokenEntity): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM token WHERE id = :id")
    suspend fun getTokenInfo(id: String): TokenEntity

}   



@Module
    @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
    object NetworkModule {
    
        private val json = Json {
            encodeDefaults = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        }
    
        @OptIn(InternalAPI::class)
        @Singleton
        @Provides
        fun provideKtorHttpClient(
            tokenRepository: TokenRepository,
            tokenDao: TokenDao
        ): HttpClient {
            return HttpClient(OkHttp) {
                //Json Setting
                install(JsonFeature) {
                    serializer = KotlinxSerializer(json = json)
                }
                //Logging Setting
                install(Logging) {
                    logger = object : Logger {
                        override fun log(message: String) {
                            Timber.d("api log: $message")
                        }
                    }
                    logger = Logger.DEFAULT
                    level = LogLevel.ALL
                }
                //Timeout Setting
                install(HttpTimeout) {
                    requestTimeoutMillis = 15_000
                    connectTimeoutMillis = 15_000
                    socketTimeoutMillis = 15_000
                }
    
                //Default Request Setting
                defaultRequest {
                    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                    accept(ContentType.Application.Json)
                    headers {
                        append("Accept-Version", "v1")
                        CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
                            val authToken = tokenDao.getTokenInfo("auth_token")
                            authToken?.let {
                                append(HttpHeaders.Authorization, authToken.token)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    url {
                        protocol = URLProtocol.HTTP
                        host = Constants.BASE_URL
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When sending a request to the backend server,
if there is a value stored in the room, put it in the authorization of the header and
try not to send it if there is no value.
Therefore, if I call the value from the room with CorutineScope, and if value is empty,
just skip
But although there is a value, the header does not include the value.
When using Ktor, how should I implement the part where I put autorization depending on the presence or absence of token in the value of the header?

Answer (score 1):

Ktor is not an opinionated web client.

Dynamically setting the header on the client builder would work as well as having two instances of the client, one with authentication and the other without it.

From the code you've pasted I believe the less complex thing may be to always provide an unauthenticated client and set the header as soon as the request needs to go off but it's really up to you

Comment: Agree to that! We faced the same issue in our KMM project and had to resort to the same. Just saw this Question today to see if anything improved.